# CSS3 navigation hyperlinks skew

Tags: css

I am creating the navigation menu with the new CSS3 skew propoerty. Is there any way to leave the hyperlinks not transformed? Here's my code:

```
ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
}

.menu li{float:left; height: 31px;  margin-right:10px; padding:0 5px; -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'prevent' the `skew` transformation, since it affects the whole of the content box of that element. But you *can* compensate for it by, using the `skew` on the `a` element itself to 'reverse' the `skew` of the parent element:

```
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); /* the negative skew value of the parent element */
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sjUSv/).

Note: `skew` seems, from experimentation with Chromium on Ubuntu, only to affect elements of `display: block`, which is why the `a` css, above, includes that declaration.